# State change doesn't show dialog in React Native View

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I've got a state to show a dialog inside a React

```
const [isConfirmationDialogVisible, setConfirmationDialogVisibility] = useState(false);
```

I set the visibility state when a button is clicked:

```
<Button id={item.id} 
            onPressCallback={() => setConfirmationDialogVisibility(true)} />
```

The visibility state is passed on to the dialog like this (isOwnItem is true):

```
<> ...
        {isOwnItem && <Dialog
            id={item.content.id}
            visible={isConfirmationDialogVisible}
        />}
</>
```

The visibility property is set inside the dialog from the dialog properties:

```
const [isVisible, setVisibility] = useState(props.visible);
```

and is passed on to an alert like this:

```
<StyledAlert show={isVisible} ... />
```

The alert has worked before, so I think the problem is not there.

Now, when I click the button, nothing happens. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you try to console.log `isVisible` to see if it's passed down correctly?

Comment: I have debugged it and it was set correctly inside the dialog props, but I will probably try to log it, to get more specific information.

Answer (score 0):

By setting it into state (with `useState`), the value for `props.visible` will be set only on mount. It's an inital value, it won't be updated by `props.visible` changing; it will only update when `setVisibility` is called.

When `Dialog` mounts, it will get the correct value, but new value set by `setConfirmationDialogVisibility` won't update the value of `isVisible`

If you need to change the state from inside `Dialog`, pass the state setter:

```js
<> ...
        {isOwnItem && <Dialog
            id={item.content.id}
            visible={isConfirmationDialogVisible}
            setVisible={setConfirmationDialogVisibility}
        />}
</>
```

If not, you could simply do away with setting the inner state:

```js
// not needed
// const [isVisible, setVisibility] = useState(props.visible);

<StyledAlert show={props.visible} ... />
```

If you really must keep the inner state, AND you don't want to pass the parent state setter, then you need a useEffect that updates the inner state when the outer state changes:

```js
const [isVisible, setVisibility] = useState(props.visible);

useEffect(() => {
  setVisibility(props.visible)
}, [props.visible])
```

NOTE: I would not recommend this last method as there is a lot of redundant code

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It sounds though, as if the dialog should become visible on button click and won't be able to set itself invisible again. The problem is though, that it doesn't become visible in the first place.

Comment: @nemu that is likely because it has already mounted and the initial value has been set as false. But when you set it as true (from the parent), it has not remounted and the inner state of is still false. The 3 codeblocks in my answer are for 3 different solutions, I would reiterate that you probably shouldn't be setting the state in both the parent and child.

Answer (score 0):

I added a console output to the onPressCallback of the button and realised that isVisible was always false when the button was pressed.

I have solved it now by adding the isVisible condition to the part where I call the dialog:

```
{isOwnItem && isConfirmationDialogVisible && <Dialog
    id={item.content.id}
    visible={isConfirmationDialogVisible}
/>}
```